# Error when uploading Symfony project in the server with two different PHP version

Tags: php, linux, symfony

Currently, I have two different PHP version in the server: **PHP version 5.2.11** wherein this is the original PHP version in the server. **PHP version 5.4.44** php version that is uploaded and set up in the server and this is also the php that the project uses. The project uses Symfony Framework and this is the reason why install another php version on the server. After the successful installation of another php version, we already upload the Symfony Project and with an extension of **.zip**. Then unzip the file and try to run in the browser using the server name. Unfortunately, it has error and error states something like this :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with
>   message '[ERROR 3070] CT 'container': The content model is not
>   determinist. (in
>   file:////home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd
>   - line 20, column 0)' in /home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php:96
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(218):
>   Symfony\Component\Config\Util\XmlUtils::loadFile('/home/sanchez/...',
>   Array) #1
>   /home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(41):
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->parseFileToDOM('/home/sanchez/...')
>    /home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php(48):
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLo in
>   /home/sanchez/ProjectName/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php
>   on line 220

By the way I am using **Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4**. How can I fix this error? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

After running this command `rpm -Uvh libxml2*.rpm` I got this error.

```
warning: only V3 signatures can be verified, skipping V4 signature
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libdl.so.2()(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libm.so.6()(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libz.so.1()(64bit) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by libxml2-2.7.2-1.x86_64
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) setools-2.3-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libxslt-1.1.11-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libxml2-python-2.6.16-10.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) xmlsec1-1.2.6-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) xmlsec1-openssl-1.2.6-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libbonobo-2.8.0-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) alchemist-1.0.34-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) shared-mime-info-0.15-10.1.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) GConf2-2.8.1-1.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libglade2-2.4.0-5.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgnomecanvas-2.8.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) pygtk2-libglade-2.4.0-2.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-vfs2-2.8.2-8.6.EL4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libbonoboui-2.8.0.99cvs20040929-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgnomeui-2.8.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-python2-2.6.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-python2-bonobo-2.6.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) Omni-0.9.1-7.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) foomatic-3.0.2-3.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gstreamer-0.8.7-4.EL.0.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libcroco-0.6.0-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libsoup-2.2.1-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) scrollkeeper-0.3.14-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libwmf-0.2.8.3-5.7.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gstreamer-plugins-0.8.5-1.EL.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gtkhtml2-2.6.2-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) firefox-1.5.0.12-0.3.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) ggv-2.8.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-desktop-2.8.0-5.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-python2-gtkhtml2-2.6.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) krb5-auth-dialog-0.2-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgsf-1.10.1-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) evolution-data-server-1.0.2-14.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-panel-2.8.1-8.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-pilot-2.0.12-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) usermode-gtk-1.74-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) rhn-applet-2.1.25-22.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgnomeprint22-2.8.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgnomeprintui22-2.8.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gpdf-2.8.2-7.7.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) librsvg2-2.8.1-1.el4.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) eel2-2.8.1-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gdm-2.6.0.5-7.rhel4.15.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) kdelibs-3.3.1-9.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libxklavier-1.02-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-kerberos-0.3.3-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) xscreensaver-4.18-5.rhel4.14.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) file-roller-2.8.1-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gconf-editor-2.8.0-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-keyring-manager-0.0.3-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-media-2.8.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-netstatus-2.8.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-applets-2.8.0-9.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-system-monitor-2.7.0-8.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-terminal-2.7.3-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-utils-2.8.0-5.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gok-0.11.8-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libgail-gnome-1.1.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnopernicus-0.9.12-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) NetworkManager-gnome-0.3.1-4.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) vino-2.8.1-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gtksourceview-1.1.0-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gthumb-2.4.2-7.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) eog-2.8.1-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gedit-2.8.1-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) nautilus-2.8.1-4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) control-center-2.8.0-12.rhel4.5.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-volume-manager-1.1.0-5.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) gnome-session-2.8.0-7.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) nautilus-cd-burner-2.8.3-6.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) nautilus-media-0.8.1-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) desktop-printing-0.17-3.EL.1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) yelp-2.6.4-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) perl-XML-LibXML-Common-0.13-7.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) perl-XML-LibXML-1.58-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libxml2-devel-2.6.16-10.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) libbonoboui-devel-2.8.0.99cvs20040929-2.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) glade2-2.6.0-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) bug-buddy-2.8.0-3.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) seamonkey-1.0.9-2.el4.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by (installed) devhelp-0.10-0.8.el4.i386
        libxml2 = 2.6.16 is needed by (installed) libxml2-python-2.6.16-10.i386
        libxml2 = 2.6.16 is needed by (installed) libxml2-devel-2.6.16-10.i386
```

How can I possibly solve this?

Comment: can you give me steps on how can I upgrade libxml2 ?  and can it affect other programs that uses my current version which is 2.6.16

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228184 - I don't know it can affect any programs or no, and don't know it help you or no, just many people report this problem, and it's related to outdated `libxml2`. You have to check yourself.

Comment: okay,, thanks :) i'll check this  out

Comment: Consider using `yum` to install all dependencies.

Comment: how should I do it? I am a newbie to this,,, :)

Comment: Just `yum install libxml2` ?

Comment: yum command not found

Comment: Are you logged as admin? or `sudo yum install libxml2`.

Comment: its still command not found

Comment: So find the way to update package on your OS, I'm not familiar with rhel, I always use debian family distros.

Comment: aside from this do you have any idea on how should I do it? since I find an options and that is to upgrade Red Hat version to 5 or 6 ; update all the 81 dependencies and must find the newer version and lastly is to use the `up2date -u` command but my mentor won't allow to use any of these options since it will takes time and at the same time some of the programs may be affected  and we need to test it again and again.